# Using Carbon for Laravel queries

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

how can I use Carbon to output `created_at` human readable queries like Facebook's `1 min ago` on it's posts. The problem is I always return the results of the query to output in the browser directly. How can I integrate it so instead of `2015-07-01 12:32:43` it would be `1 min ago` or other that's human readable and nice.

In my controller:

```
    $posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->where('author_id', '=', $id)
                ->where('created_at', '<', $date)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);

    return $posts;
```

It will then return a json format of all posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use an Eloquent model and the features that come with it:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    protected $appends = array('created_at_for_humans');

    public function getCreatedAtForHumansAttribute(){
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->diffForHumans();
    }
}
```

This [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) returns the formatted date and because it is registered in `$appends` the attribute will be included for array/JSON conversion.

And your query would look nearly the same:

```
$posts = Post::where('author_id', '=', $id)
             ->where('created_at', '<', $date)
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
             ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
foreach ($posts as &$post) {
   $post->created_at = Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->diffForHumans();
}
```

before `return`

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I just need to remove `&` in your `$post`. Typo.